# working java Hibernate 3.3.2.GA offline?

Tags: java, xml, dtd

I am having problems parsing Hibernate's XML offline.  I need to know how to specify the DTD when there is no network connection. Here is my Hibernate config.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
   "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
   <!-- Database connection settings -->
 <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/global_data</property>
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password">pass</property>
```

.
.
.

I have tried to change the PUBLIC to SYSTEM in the xml config and still get an error as well.  I am using eclipse IDE and I just point my project build path to the user lib that I manually import all the hibernate lib into.

Comment: So you are trying to get the eclipse auto-suggest working in an offline enviroment?

Comment: hmm currently my project is using the java hibernate API and when loading or compiling, the API requires internet connection to work.. if i am offline i will get errors in parse the hibernate.cfg.xml. currently i need a way to make it work offline

Comment: This really was a question about XML and DTDs.  You should really reword the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the mapping to your eclipse IDE.  To do this navigate to the XML -> XML Catalog menu.  Then you need to add an entry.  For location you will need to specify where the dtd file lives.  There is a way to look up files within a jar, but I can't find how to do it at the moment.  For the key type you would select Public ID or System ID based on what keyword you have `PUBLIC` or `SYSTEM`.  Then for the key you would put `-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN`, Optionally supply the address `http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd` in the alternative web address field.

For ease of use I have found it useful to find the dtd within a jar, then put it in a project called resources in my workspace, but specifying the jar location would be more correct.

Comment: for the location, is it ok for me to just point to my hibernate3.jar file? hmm seems like  i am wrong.. need to point to the dtd file but i cant find it any where....

Comment: You would have to point to the DTD within the file, I don't recall the exact correct way to do this but something like `jar:file:/path/to/jar/<jar-name>.jar!/path/to/dtd/<dtd-name>.dtd`

Comment: tried that above for the location...still cant get it work...hmm basically there is no hard copy file for the dtd?

Comment: Just found out the specification for locating files in a jar, edited my comment above, try that.

Comment: just a question, do i need to put the jar name by renaming the <jar-name>.jar and <dtd-name>.dtd as well? or just copy paste the whole thing without editting it? i tried copied the whole thing but still cant work...and does my user lib which consist the hibernate lib requires to be in my workspace folder? currently it resides at my dropbox...but if i shift to my src folder it seems like having error while importing all the hibernate jar file...having message of missing file...

Comment: jar:file:/C:/Users/john/Dropbox/hibernate3 lib/hibernate3.jar!/path/to/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd this is my path but problem is i am not sure wat to replace at /path/to/dtd/

Comment: If my hibernate3.jar is the same as yours: `jar:file:/C:/Users/john/Dropbox/hibernate3 lib/hibernate3.jar!/org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd`

Comment: hmm is not working for me =( i am using version 3.3.2 hibernate3.jar...will it effect this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10763/discussion-between-vari-and-user1217609)

Answer (score 0):

My quick 2-step solution:

1)   Create an empty file named hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd in the same eclipse package where your hibernate.cfg.xml resides.

Then, while you're online, download/copy the text found at  http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd into the empty dtd file you created.

2)   Now, when you're offline, change the 2nd line in your hibernate.cfg.xml from this

!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

to this

!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "classpath:///hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

(Please note that I had to remove the leading less-than character to get the !DOCTYPE to show in this answer.... so be sure to type it back in at the start of your 2nd line)

I save both 'online' and 'offline' settings in a comment at the bottom of my xml so I can switch back and forth.